# Selenium Webdriver Error - SessionNotCreatedError

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm developing automated tests with Capybara on ruby. And I'm struggling to solve this error for days. I've tried to change chrome/chromedriver versions to every combination on earth and still getting errors! I've also reinstalled cucumber/ruby/devkit etc..

By the way, my automated tests were working pretty well, and suddenly they were not anymore.

Someone helps please!

```
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:69:in `assert_ok': session not created exception (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError)
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

```
    require 'capybara'
    require 'selenium-webdriver'

    Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
        Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
            app,
            browser: :chrome
        )
    end

    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = 'C:\tools\chromedriver.exe'
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = 'C:\tools\chrome64_54.0.2840.71\chrome.exe'

    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

    url = "https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara"
    internet = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
    internet.visit url

    sleep(20)
```

Comment: You need to show your current configuration for anyone to have any chance of answering this.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 x64, Ruby 2.3.3p222. Capybara 2.7.1, Selenium WebDriver 3.0.3. Chrome 55.0.2883.75 m.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your Capybara config - although if you're using selenium 3.x you'll want to update capybara to something newer than 2.7.1

Comment: I just upgraded Capybara to (2.11.0) and nothing yet.

Comment: And add your current capybara configuration code to the question please

Comment: Assuming there are no obvious errors in your capybara configuration (once you add it) then you should check that you're running the latest chromedriver (2.26 as of now, although 2.25 should work with your chrome version) and make sure you don't have any old versions left around in the path

Comment: As you said, I've just downloaded the 2.26 version, and checked for more chromewebdriver versions on path. But not worked till now..

Comment: Is there any more info to the error message ?

Comment: Added all error message on question.

Comment: Sorry - I'm out of suggestins

Comment: Ok, thanks for the effort!!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest try downgrading your Chrome version to `v54` or `v50` and try then. From your error log it seems a http request is not being established and so the webdriver is unable to create a session. Integrate a Selenium standalone server in your project and try running the tests then. The latest version is `v3.0.1`, you can download it from here:

http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/